# Пропала реактивность при отделении логики в Composition API

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue3

Всем привет.

Начал рефактирить код под Composition API, вынося логику в сервисы.

И столкнулся с трудностью.

У меня есть свойство которое я вынес в сервис

```
  const switchAdd = ref(false)
```

Это свойство содержит, значение в зависимости от которого отрисовываются элементы в компоненте.

Пока это свойство было внутри компонентиа проблем не было.

Но, после того как я вынес его в отдельный сервис
и продключил вот так в компоненте :

```
import serviceAbonent from '@/services/abonent'
... const { swithAdd } = = serviceAbonent()
```

у свойства пропала реактивность.
Я добавил логи и при клике на кнопку, которая меняет значение этого свойства значение изменяется в сервисе, но не изменяется в компоненте.

Нокже сломались еще некоторые свойства, но думаю, если поможете в чем проблема с этим свойством, то смогу и остальные исправить.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, функция неправильно экспортирована из serviceAbonent.js

Если serviceAbonent экспортирован не по дефолту, то при импорте в компоненте деструктуризуем (import { serviceAbonent } from '@/services/abonent')

Либо надо было написать в serviceAbonent.js: export default function serviceAbonent...

Пример https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-leaf-esvbm1?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: Алина, спасибо за ответ.
Но у меня все так и сделано :) 
Сервис экспортируется по дефолту

Comment: ну тогда желательно, чтоб вы фрагмент кода своего сделали тоже в сандбоксе каком нибудь, там глянуть, а то слишком много мест, где еще может быть ошибка)

Comment: Удалось разобраться. Нужно было вынести переменную swithAdd  за пределы функции сервиса serviceAbonent(). 
Но и вам спасибо за помощь )

Comment: да кстати, при обращении из разных компонентов serviceAbonent() возвращает разные экземпляры, поэтому в таком случае работает вынос переменной наружу из функции. удачи с composition api ))